# Como fazer GROUP BY em UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
String select1 = @"SELECT CODIGOB, DESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE FROM " + path + @"\IVENDA.DBF WHERE DATA BETWEEN {^" + datainicial + "} AND {^" + datafinal + @"} ";

String select2 = @"SELECT CODIGOB, DESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE FROM " + path + @"\NFCEI.DBF WHERE DATAE BETWEEN {^" + datainicial + "} AND {^ " + datafinal + @"} ";

String instrucao1 = @"SELECT CODIGOB, DESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE FROM (" + select1 + ")VND " + @"UNION All " + select2 + " ";

String sql= @"SELECT CODIGOB, DESCRICAO, QUANTIDADE FROM (" + instrucao1 + ")SQL GROUP BY CODIGOB, DESCRICAO ORDER BY QUANTIDADE DESC";
```

Ao fazer a instrução 1  ele nao deixa eu usar o GROUP BY. Alguem saberia o porque ? Como eu devo usar o `GROUP BY` quando tenho `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Você notou que está usando `select1` como subquery, porém `select2` está sendo usada diretamente? Se você usar `select2` como subquery também, creio que seus problemas se resolvam

Comment: Você deve fazer primeiro o `union` com todos os dados e agrupar depois. Se necessário, faça um `select into` em uma tabela temporária com todos os campos necessários, depois faça o `group by` a partir dessa tabela

Comment: Sempre escreva a consulta num browser de sql antes de tentar por num programa que fale com o SGBD. Ajuda a pegar erros muito mais

Comment: @RicardoPontual, no caso, cte é mais apropriada para este uso https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/mysql-80-common-table-expressions/

Comment: Seu problema não está no `GROUP BY` e sim, no `ORDER BY` dentro das subconsultas. Mova-o para a query final e teste novamente.

Comment: Também é uma opção @JeffersonQuesado, só resta saber se a dúvida é sobre `MySql` :-) De qualquer forma tem implementações para outros bancos de dados, é uma boa sugestão.

Comment: Construindo a query no `SQLServer` da mesma forma como ele criou, é possível, mas, não quando se utiliza o `order by` internamente. Assim como também não é possível em `VIEWS`.  **A cláusula ORDER BY é inválida em exibições, funções embutidas, tabelas derivadas, subconsultas e expressões de tabela comuns, a menos que TOP, OFFSET ou FOR XML também esteja especificado.**

Comment: @RicardoPontual, você está certo. Eu pensei ter lido a tag MySql. Segue cte genericamente : https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression

Comment: @ismael nao tenho problema com `ORDER BY`, até tirei das query porem o que esta com erro mesmo e no `group by`

Comment: Agora que vi em sua primeira query que você está utilizando o campo errado no `group by`. A coluna chama `DESCPROD` e no `group by` você usou **descricao**. Já corrigiu isso?

Comment: @ismael Fiz alteração como você falou. Da uma olhada a coluna 'DESCPROD' esta correto. O que acontece agora da certo porem ele não agrupa os itens que tem quantidade diferente. E se eu tirar a quantidade da erro na query sql.

Comment: @FabioC Sua última consulta não deveria ser: `String sql= @"SELECT DESCRICAO, sum(QUANTIDADE) FROM (" + instrucao1 + ")SQL GROUP BY DESCRICAO ORDER BY QUANTIDADE DESC";` Não entendi pq retirou o `SUM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para efetuar o agrupamento necessário, você terá que utilizar a função de agregação `SUM`. E retirar o campo *quantidade* do `group by`.

```
String sql= @"SELECT DESCRICAO, SUM(QUANTIDADE) FROM (" + instrucao1 + ")SQL GROUP BY DESCRICAO ORDER BY QUANTIDADE DESC";
```

Comment: Juro que fiz isso deu erro, eu coloquei mais um campo ficou 'CODIGOB' deu certo.